# Single user boot : remove read only

Tags: terminal, startup, recovery

My OS keeps rebooting since I installed photoshop.

Save mode didn't help.

Trying now too boot on single user, I have a UI to unlock my user account (the mac is encrypted) then I have the command line.

I'm trying to remove everything from Adobe on the launch agent but I can't

`sudo rm -rf com.adobe.AAM.Uploader-1.0.plist` returns "read only file system" and don't even ask for my password!

Am I good for a reinstall or anything I can do to remove theses files / or fix my boot issue

I'm running 10.11

---

Update: I forget I need to mount the HD first.  I'm trying now

Comment: Can you get into photoshop at all, or does it crash before you could get to prefs? If you can get to prefs, disable the hardware acceleration, Prefs > Performance [maybe reduce allowed RAM while you're in that panel.

Comment: @Tetsujin I have so crash at the end of the installer, and now straight at boot. Rebooted on single user and I removed every adobe file (I think)

Comment: Then you need to hone your question - photoshop isn't crashing if it's not even installed yet.

Answer (score 1):

`Fsck` followed by `mount -uw` / fixed my problem.

Comment: Ps I still have the Sam boot following but a death screen... Any idea?